# How do I the get touched coordinates using the xui library 

Tags: javascript, touch, mobile-webkit, xui

How do I get the coordinates that the user touches? I am using [xui](http://xuijs.com/) and Javascript.

On my index.html I do not know how to get the x and y coordinates from a user interaction.

Answer (score 1):

if you use xui for event binding then the event callback function gets [`TocuhEvent`](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/UserExperience/Reference/TouchEventClassReference/TouchEvent/TouchEvent.html#//apple_ref/javascript/cl/TouchEvent) object (**e**) as its parameter

```
x$('.a_button').on('touchstart', function(e) {
    // whatever
});
```

Now TouchEvent isn't like MouseEvent where you can have only one input at a time - as TouchEvent object handles multitouch multiple touches at the same time.

To get the touch that was captured on your element you have to get it from `e.touches` - which is all touches currently active on the device, `e.targetTouches` - all the touches which are on the current target `.a_button` in our example or `e.changedTouches` - touches which triggered the event. For touchstart (best responsiveness) you can grab first element of `e.changedTouches` as it will be the touch that triggered your `touchstart` event to get the `Touch` object representing your touch.

Now [`Touch`](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/UserExperience/Reference/TouchClassReference/Touch/Touch.html#//apple_ref/javascript/cl/Touch) object holds all the data you need to get any info on what's happening on the screen.

```
x$('.a_button').on('touchstart', function(e) {
    var touch = e.changedTouches[0];
    alert(touch.pageX + ' ' + touch.pageY);
});
```